# JSON algorithm, inconsistency?

Tags: javascript, json, database

In google chrome, I have tried this:

I had a object in javascript, for example,

```
var b = {
    text: 'hello world, you "cool"'
};
```

Then I used JSON.stringify to convert it to string, and send to db, in db, it will look like this:

```
{"text":"hello world, you \"cool\""}
```

Then I get it from db on server, and try to send back to js then parse it, certainly it's a valid JSON string, but with this way to pass it to javascript by server scripting language:

```
"javascript:loadText(' + str + ')"...
```

which the `loadText` is a javascript function:

```
function loadText(val) {

   console.log(JSON.parse(val));
}
```

We will get error, but if we try another way in javascript only, no this error:

```
var b = {
    text: 'hello world, you "cool"'
};

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b)));
```

And is it because JSON stringify/parse algorithm?

PS:

This is wrong too:

```
loadText('{"text":"hello world, you \"cool\""}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `"javascript:loadText(' + str + ')"` is literally attempting to pass the text `+ str +` to `loadText`.

You can either fix your quoting or make the `'`s indirectly:

```
javascript:loadText(String.fromCharCode(39) + str + String.fromCharCode(39))
```

Comment: @Mr.Liama thanks, furthermore what you think of this, JSON.parse('{"text":"hello world, you \"cool\""'), that's error one too, unless JSON.parse('{"text":"hello world, you \\"cool\\""}'), I am curious about it, because the algorithm did this way...

Comment: If you're manually putting the string in, then yes, you'll need to escape the ```\```s, otherwise they'll be removed.  To help explain it, try doing: `var str = '{"text":"hello world, you \"cool\""}'; console.log(str);`.  You'll see why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mr.LIama Thanks, got your point, the \" just as same as " in string in JSON.parse, but when we use the string in jsonlint, it regard \ as a char, so it's valid, but actually not same thing in expression.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to debug JavaScript errors by looking at server side code.

Look at the JS you are generating.

```
"javascript:loadText(' + str + ')"
```

Is going to give you something like:

```
"javascript:loadText({"text":"hello world, you \"cool\""})"
```

So you have a JavaScript object literal and not a string of JSON.

You would have to wrap the data with quotes and escape any special characters in order to preserve it as JSON when embedded it in JS.

Given the location, you should then URL encode it too.

Comment: Not that simple, even you have loadText('{"text":"hello world, you \"cool\""}'); it's still wrong and throw error.

Comment: @Tom Sure you need to escape `\ ` as well. `loadText('{"text":"hello world, you \\\"cool\\\""}')` You need both symbols `\ and "` while `\"` - is one symbol. Try `'"' === '\"'`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Yes, that's true, actually we need \\" not \", but the confused part is, the string is valid JSON, but can't get correct result from JSON.parse()

Comment: @Tom — It isn't valid JSON by the time it has been passed through the HTML and JavaScript parsers.